# Best way to interpret results from tf model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

First off, I'm a TensorFlow noobie, so I appreciate any clarity that can be given in my understanding of anything TF.

I am wondering if I am approaching my project correctly. Currently, I am using [this](https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1) model to identify birds in pictures. I am getting the correct results from the output, but am wondering what would be the best way to automate the interpretation of the results. Currently, I have just done quick tests by inputting an image, and then manually scanning for which values the largest, and then finding the corresponding label in the labelmap.csv file found on the previous link.

I have been researching and see that a lot of models use a labelmap.pbtxt, and so I am wondering if I am supposed to make something like that. My other thought was to find the largest value in the output and then go to that index in the CSV to get the result, but I am unsure if this is the correct TensorFlow way of interpreting results.

Thanks for any clarification you can give!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to store the ground truth for the test set in an array and regarding the largest value you are talking about, `tf.argmax` is used to get the maximum value and then, comparing it with the ground truth stored. You don't need to see for the maximum value yourself, let the code do that.

You can also use `model.evaluate` function in TensorFlow to directly get results.